# Making a computed property dependent on all the properties of another object in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to make a property dependent on all the properties of another object? For example: ([also in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgZ94/2/)):

html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <p>Weapon damage: {{ input value=model.activeWeapon.damage}} </p>
    <p>Hero damage: {{ model.weaponDamagePerSecond }}</p>
</script>
```

javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Weapon = Ember.Object.extend({
    damage: null,
    speed: null
});

App.Hero = Ember.Object.extend({
    activeWeapon: null,
    strength: null,
    weaponDamagePerSecond: function() {
      var weapon = this.get('activeWeapon');
      console.log('weapon damage:' + weapon.get('damage'));
      console.log('weapon speed:' + weapon.get('speed'));
      console.log('strength:' + this.get('strength'));
      console.log (weapon.get('damage') + this.get('strength')) * weapon.get('speed');

      return (1.0 * weapon.get('damage') + 1.0 * this.get('strength')) * weapon.get('speed');
    }.property('activeWeapon', 'strength')
    //}.property('activeWeapon.damage', 'activeWeapon.speed', 'strength')
    // the above line will make the example work, but it is a bit painful to 
    // have to specify all the attributes needed of activeWeapon.
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Hero.create({
            activeWeapon: App.Weapon.create({
                damage: 40,
                speed: 2
            }),
            strength: 8
        });
    }
});
```

Is it possible to get `weaponDamagePerSecond` to update when any property on `activeWeapon` updates, with having to specify all the properties manually (like in the commented out code)?

Comment: Maybe try `activeWeapon.*`. But don't know if this works. Just an idea.

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately (causes an error `TypeError: path.match(...) is null`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to observe all object property changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388402/how-to-observe-all-object-property-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it's really easy to write up an observer that watches everything and triggers your computed property to update anytime it updates.  I'm not necessarily recommending this, but it can be done.

http://jsfiddle.net/5gS59/

```
App.Weapon = Ember.Object.extend({
    damage: null,
    speed: null,
    version: 0,
    watchingEverything: function(){
        console.log('hello');
        this.incrementProperty('version');
    }.observes('damage','speed')
});


weaponDamagePerSecond: function() {
  var weapon = this.get('activeWeapon');
  console.log('weapon damage:' + weapon.get('damage'));
  console.log('weapon speed:' + weapon.get('speed'));
  console.log('strength:' + this.get('strength'));
  console.log (weapon.get('damage') + this.get('strength')) * weapon.get('speed');

  return (1.0 * weapon.get('damage') + 1.0 * this.get('strength')) * weapon.get('speed');
}.property('activeWeapon.version', 'strength')
```

You can alternately do a similar thing with just a property and not an observes:

http://jsfiddle.net/XsuxA/1/

Comment: Thanks, that works well enough. I am new to emberjs, so is there a reason you are not recommending this? Ie is there a different way to design this to do what I want?

Comment: The beauty of computed properties is it doesn't cause a property to be updated unless something is dependent on it.  If you had another property watching the version, and only using damage, but the speed changed it would force that property to recalculate even though it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: That makes sense, I wasn't hitting any speed issues with my practice programs, but it is obviously an important concern for bigger programs.