# How to observe all object property changes?

Tags: object, ember.js, properties, foreach

For arrays I know you can do something like this:

```
function() {
}.observes("array.@each")
```

What I did was convert the object into an array and observe the properties with a @each, but is there a better way to observe object all property changes without converting it into an array?

Comment: Does function() {}.observes("array.@each") actually work?  According to the answers here, there's no way to observe any property within an array: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24893070/188740

Comment: it's actually been a while since i've used this kind of observer, but I do recall it working correctly. it must behave the same way as the array.[] from kingpin2k's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe `isDirty` to see if any of the object's values have been modified since last save (if you are using Ember Data).

Alternatively you can pass a comma separated list of properties to `observes`. This might be long if you have a lot of properties on your object, but will work.

A third approach could be to override `setUnknownProperty()` and set a property, a 'dirty flag' (or perform any action you may want in there.

There's also an [old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623645/ember-js-observer-for-all-values/11679850#11679850) that gives the following answer:

```
App.WatchedObject = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstProp: null,
  secondProp: "bar",

  init: function(){
    this._super();
    var self = this;
    Ember.keys(this).forEach(function(key){
      if(Ember.typeOf(self.get(key)) !== 'function'){
        self.addObserver(key, function(){
          console.log(self.get(key));
        });
      }
    }); 
  }
});
```

You could probably split this out into a Mixin to keep your code DRY.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately messing with the isDirty flag isn't reliable. Once the isDirty flag is set, it won't be toggled until it is saved. so any changes between toggled true and toggled false on save, won't be observed.

2. Sending in the whole list of observations is not DRY. I would avoid this at all costs.

3. Well, this last one could work, though I'm not a big fan of it. I want something that doesn't require setting a flag.

Comment: Yeah I agree that none of those options is ideal, but as far as I'm aware Ember does not handle this natively. I found an old SO answer and included it above

Answer (score 0):

probably you could create something like a `blabbermouth` mixin and override the `set` method to get notified of property changes:

```
App.BlabbermouthMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

  set: function(keyName, value) {
    this.set('updatedProperty', keyName);
    this._super(keyName, value);
  }

});
```

and observe the `updatedProperty` property?

Comment: this won't flag subsequent modifications of the same property, until another property is changed in the process. Also, are you sure all property changes go via `set`? What about if we change the object's properties using `object.setProperties`? Does that method uses `set` internally?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of properties in an object and apply them to a new property:

```
attrs = Ember.keys(observedObject);
var c = Ember.computed(function() {
    // Do stuff when something changes
})
Ember.defineProperty(target, propertyName, c.property.apply(c, attrs));
```

Here is a working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/corenucopenu/1/edit).  Creating an observer instead of a property should be possible using a similar approach.