# Ember observable map

Tags: ember.js

This should be easy, but I can't figure it out.  I am creating a view that behaves a bit like a tri-state multiple select, and the core component is a property on the view which lists each option and its status:

```
TriState = Ember.View.extend({
    ...
    childView: TristateItem,
    selectionStates: {}
});

TristateItem = Ember.View.extend({
    ...
    selectedState: function() {
        var value = this.get('value');
        var states = this.get('parentView.selectionStates');
        var state = states[value];
        if (Ember.isNone(state))
            return 0;
        return state;
    }.property('value', 'parentView.selectionStates'),

    click: function(event) {
        var states = this.get('parentView.selectionStates');
        var value = this.get('value');
        var newState = states[value];
        if (Ember.isNone(newState) || newState == 0)
            newState = 1;
        else if (newState == 1)
            newState = -1;
        else
            newState = 0;
        states[value] = newState;
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

So after a few clicks, the value of `selectionStates` might be

```
{0: 1,   // value "0" is selected with state "1"
 3: -1,  // value "3" is selected with state "-1"
 4: 0}   // value "4" is not selected
```

This works fine, but the value of `TristateItem.selectedState` doesn't change.  I assume that this is because it is not possible to observe a javascript object, but I can't find anything observable in Ember that is equivalent.  How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388402/how-to-observe-all-object-property-changes

Comment: I saw that, but there are two problems.  First, it looks like serious overkill for my problem.  Second, I don't know the property names in advance.  They are dynamically added and removed.

Comment: I did this before and I wrote my own `ObservableMap` class. It's not too difficult. I'll see if I can find it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting the property, you can just use notifyPropertyChange to inform the other computed property that the parent object is dirty in some way.

```
this.notifyPropertyChange('parentView.selectionStates');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tokese/1/edit