# How should I observe a dynamic set of attributes so that observers get fired any time an attribute is set or changed?

Tags: ember.js

I'm relatively new to the Ember world and have run into a snag.

I've got a search grid with a variable number of filters (set dynamically) that can trigger a change of the search results.  Because the filters are set dynamically, I won't know their names (and can't set properties on my controller which I would then observe).

I've set up a JSBin here that shows what I'm attempting: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/walipuceta/1/

I'm wanting to have the `filterValuesWatcher` observer log to the console when any value is set on the `filterValues` object / property.  In essence I'd like to have an `observes('filterValues.*')` in effect.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388402/how-to-observe-all-object-property-changes ?

Comment: @DRobinson Probably not a duplicate, but related :-)  Thanks!  I've also just found this link that is somewhat similar: https://gist.github.com/mudassir0909/7315894