# Ember computed property for object attribute

Tags: ember.js

My component receives an object property named "line" and a string property named "name".

```
{{field-row line=model name=fieldName}}
```

The line object has several attributes. The following Ember computed property "value" returns the value based on the given line and name:

```
value: Ember.computed('line', function() {
    const line = this.get('line');
    const name = this.get('name');
    return line.get(name);
})
```

This works, but any updates to the line object's attribute won't automatically trigger a refresh on the component's template. I guess that's because the reference to the 'line' object remains the same while its attribute content changes. Since the name of the attribute can not be known beforehand, I tried this but it doesn't work either:

```
value: Ember.computed('line.@each', function() {
    const line = this.get('line');
    const name = this.get('name');
    return line.get(name);
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to observe all object property changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388402/how-to-observe-all-object-property-changes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: the following used to work but was not intended by the framework authors. Instead of using `set`, use `defineProperty` instead. See this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/16504)

Well, if you know all of the possible attributes ahead of time, you can use the brace syntax:

```
value: Ember.computed('line.{length,width}', function(){
    var line = this.get('line');
    var name = this.get('name');
    return line.get(name);
  })
```

as this [JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jeleteduqe/1/edit?html,js,output) demonstrates

But, if you want truly dynamic behavior:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  value:null,
  initialize: function(){
    var name = this.get('name');
    var key = "line." + name;
    this.set('value', Ember.computed(key, function(){
    var line = this.get('line');
    var name = this.get('name');
    return line.get(name);
  }));
  }.on('init')

});
```

[JSBIN numero dos](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lezibehifi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: thank you1 I ended up wit hthe brace-expanded list of properties (your first suggestion). It would have been nice to use a dynamic behavior but the second suggestion is very verbose

Comment: Great response, thanks. Still works for me in Ember 2.12, even when all object attributes are arrays, with syntax like: `myObject.{field1,field2}.[]'`.